A call of ssh breaks i/o-redirection in a bash-script
Given the script
$ cat save_stdin.sh 
#!/bin/bash

# save stdin
exec 3<&0

echo " intermediate output independing from stdin:"
echo "This is a test " | grep "test" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'

# reset stdin
exec 0<&3

echo -e "\n work with original stdin:"
ssh localhost grep "piped" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'

# close saved stdin
exec 3<&-

I get as expected
$ echo "this is piped" | ./save_stdin.sh 
 intermediate output independing from stdin:
THIS IS A TEST 

 work with original stdin:
THIS IS PIPED

But if I insert a command like ssh localhost ps | wc -l before the reset, it seems to destroy the saved stdin:
#!/bin/bash

# save stdin
exec 3<&0

echo " intermediate output independing from stdin:"
echo "This is a test " | grep "test" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'

##
ssh localhost ps | wc -l
##

# reset stdin
exec 0<&3

echo -e "\n work with original stdin:"
ssh localhost grep "piped" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'

# close saved stdin
exec 3<&-

gives
$ echo "this is piped" | ./save_stdin.sh 
 intermediate output independing from stdin:
THIS IS A TEST 
86

 work with original stdin:

How can I circumvent this (bug!?) without creating temporary files?


This exists in the BashFAQ: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089

...in short, ssh localhost ps </dev/null | wc -l to stop the first ssh from eating your stdin so it's still available for the second one.

BTW, you realize that exec 3<&0 saves a copy of the FD, but it doesn't make a copy of the content available to read from the FD? So in the block where the redirection is active code that reads from either FD 0 or FD 3 is consuming that same (original-stdin) source. The fd-duplication song and dance you're doing here thus has no useful practical effect.

Separately, don't use echo -e. printf '\n%s\n' "work with original stdin:" is more portable across shell configurations (even if your shell is 100% certain to be bash, with both the xpg_echo and posix flags set -- which can be enabled via environment variables, or at compile time, or with an explicit command -- echo -e will write -e on output).

Of course, maybe the comments are misleading. Thank you very much, it works with your hint ssh localhost ps </dev/null | wc -l!

Mind, if you'd changed exec 3<&0 to exec 3<&0 0</dev/null, that would have worked the way you intended (without needing the </dev/null on the first ssh call), because after saving the original stdin on FD 3, it would put something else on FD 0, so when the first ssh tried to read from fd 0 it would get /dev/null instead of the same original-stdin that you copied to fd 3.

Hmm, learned a lot! Again: Thank you very much! This works as you  suggested:
exec 3<&0 0</dev/null
